# Easy issue : Display legend in plots based on a color dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary, plot, colors, legend

My problem is simple but I can't fix it.
I want to display a legend :

Based on my dictionary "color_dict" which defines colors, variables **All** in red and **AML** in blue, I want to display a legend. Porblem is, only the first one (All red) appears.
I have tried to use color_dict.keys to access the keys of my dictionary but it doesn't seem to work.
I don't understand the problem, why would ax.legend(color_dict.keys()) only take the first key/value pair of my dictionary ? How can I fix that?

Thanks for your help

More explainations if needed:

I want to plot the legend with 'All' in red and 'AML' in blue, but these variables are in my dictionary and when I try to access it with .keys in the ax.legend() from python, it only displays the first item as you can see on the picture.

```
`
l_dtprj2= list(zip(*data_proj2))

color_dict = {'ALL': 'red','AML': 'blue'}

x = l_dtprj2[0]
y= l_dtprj2[1]
colorName = list(df3['labels'])

fig, ax, = plt.subplots()

ax.scatter(x, y, c=df3['labels'].map(color_dict) )

plt.xlabel('Component 1') #x label

plt.ylabel('Component 2') #y label




ax.legend(color_dict.keys())


plt.show()`
```

[My code AND its results (plot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArBmP.png)

[Here is the type of legend I'd like to have right below on the plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhTvZ.png)

Comment: Don't post your code as an image, add it to your question

Comment: it is not clear what you are actually trying to achieve...  are you saying that you cannot retrieve the values from the `color_dict` dictionary ?

Comment: I want to plot the legend with 'All' in red and 'AML' in blue, but these are in my dictionary and when I try to access it with .keys in the ax.legend() from python, it oly displays the first item as you can see on the picture.